# Back button in web development

Tags: browser-history, html5-history

The `history.back` in javascript doesn't work. Like this.

My scenario:

Request `page1 > page2 > page3 > page4`

Processing stuff in `page4` (redirect to) > `page2` , now I want the back button in `page2` redirect to `page1`.

**Questions**

How do we implement this ?

What is the keyword I can search for this problem ?

Comment: Why don't you use direct link location on those links. Why even bother with using javascript for these simple cases?

Answer (score 0):

window.history.back() should work.
Please can you post your code?
Please note that in order for this to work page1 needs to be in the browser's "history". Ensure that when you navigate to page 2 and click the browser's back button you are redirected to page 1. The window.history.back() does the same as the browser's back button.

Comment: the problem is it works the same as browser's back button. If you click back, it will redirect to `page4` ?

Comment: I understand the scenario now. I missed the part where you go to page 4, then to page 2. I don't think using history.back would work in this case.

Comment: 1st case: when you go page1 -> page2, then the history.back works fine. 2nd case: but when you go to page4 -> page2, history.back in page2 takes you back to page4, as expected. You would need to change it to history.go(-3), which would tell the browser to take you back 3 pages. But this wouldn't work in the 1st case. So I wouldn't  use history in your scenario.

Comment: so that's why I ask for the implementation of this case. Save in session or what ?

Comment: Why you don't just link it back to page1? Use page1.html/aspx/php/jsp instead of using JavaScript.

Comment: but we have different parameters for each pages. I want to know the best practice to save parameter, in cookies or session

Answer (score 0):

This should always work when JavaScript is turned on:

```
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Back</a>
```

To go back 2 pages, just change `-1` to `-2`:

```
<a href="javascript: history.go(-2)">Back 2 pages</a>
```

Comment: actually this is never a solution since it will mess up if you have complicated routing system. I find that I have to define the route explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just give redirection to **page1** :

```
<a href="javascript: window.location.href="pages1.html">Back</a>
```